# How to compare QueryDict

Tags: django

I am grading multiple choice questions which have multiple correct answers. You only get a point if you get all the correct answers and non of the incorrect ones.

```
    elif response.question.type == 'checkbox':
        all_correct = False
        my_answers = Answer.objects.filter(pk__in=response.answer)
        correct_answers = Answer.objects.filter(question=response.question, correct=True)

        // Can I just do this?
        if my_answers == correct_answers:
            all_correct = True

        if all_correct:
            total_correct += 1
```

Comment: No, you cannot. Because `.get` returns an object, and `.filter` returns a queryset.

Comment: so how about now? with `.filter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert query sets to list, and do comparison.

`query sets should have same sort order`

```
if list(my_answers) == list(correct_answers):
```

Comment: I have a `class Meta:ordering = ['position']` in my model so this worked PERFECT. Thanks